# Can't receive reputation notification after starting a bounty

Tags: support, reputation, bounty

I found a good answer today so I started a bounty for it. After deduction of the rep of the bounty, my net rep for today was 45. Since then it has gone to net 75 but I am not receiving any notifications.

If I click the notification button or my reputation tab, I can see the changes just fine. I am just not receiving any notifications like "+10" or "+5".

This is what my rep notification dialogue looks like:

[image]

This is what my reputation tab looks like:

[image]

So the entries are there, it's just the green "+10" notifications that are missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you clicked on it, it'll now show up. If you hadn't, it wouldn't have shown until you earned back the rep that spent on the bounty, because the top bar only shows the notification when it's a net gain since the last time you checked it. That's also why it doesn't show up if you get a downvote and a suggested edit approved - it's a net gain of 0, so it doesn't show. This is also why sometimes a phantom +1 shows up - from an answer that you downvoted.

Comment: [Yep It's showing up now](http://i.imgur.com/3l8fTR5.png)

Comment: See also https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244327/when-i-offer-a-bounty-i-dont-see-upvote-notifications and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209467/ignore-the-rep-change-caused-by-placing-bounties-in-the-achievements-reputation